# Higher than selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to select TDs that their colspan is higher than X.

```
<td colspan="8">..</td>
```

Need something like `td[colspan>=6]`

Comment: yep! you cannot use programming script in css

Answer (score 9):

There is no such selector, unfortunately.

You'd be better off defining CSS for elements that have a `colspan` attribute:

```
td[colspan] {...}
```

Then cancel them out for the finite set:

```
td[colspan='1'], td[colspan='2'], td[colspan='3'], td[colspan='4'], td[colspan='5']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this if you are sure to select from 8

```
td[colspan="8"] ~ td {
```

Comment: But please note that this is CSS Level 3 selector.

Comment: I like @kolink's answer as well, but this one seems cleaner/easier to maintain.

Comment: This does not address the question asked; it selects something completely different.